# Beamer: frametitle on the left side

Tags: beamer, titles

In a `beamer` presentation, I have a long table and to get more space, I would like to change the place of the `\frametitle{}`. Is there a way to place it in the left side of the slide?

Here is the slide I want to modify with the title side-by-side with the table:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Longtable}
\vspace{-0.2in}
\begin{center}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Longtable.pdf}
      \vspace{-0.1in}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which theme are you using? Can you please add to your question a little, complete document showing use the basic settings you are using?

Comment: Sure. I modified it. I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Thanks. More or less. I still don't understand what is the desired position for the title; since I don't have your image, it's hard for me to imagine what you mean with "the title side-by-side with the table". Could you please explain in more detail? Do you want to place it rotated and vertically near the right margin?

Comment: I thought about two side-by-side rectangular boxes. One on the right with a long table of data. One on the left, with a centered and horizontal title.

However, a rotated and vertically title near the right margin could be a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one option: instead of redefining the `framettile` template (which would imply to much work for just this), you could use two side-by-side `minipage`s or, easier, `\adjustbox` from the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package to place the title vertically centered with respect to the table; using the appropriate font and color you can get the same formatting as for standard titles. I used an image below to simulate the long table:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\adjustbox{valign=c}{{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}Longtable}}\hfill
\adjustbox{valign=c}{\includegraphics[height=.95\textheight,width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the title is longer, one can use the `minipage` option for the `\adjustbox` containing it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{figure}
\adjustbox{valign=c,minipage=0.4\textwidth}{{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}Longtable and some more text}}\hfill
\adjustbox{valign=c}{\includegraphics[height=.95\textheight,width=.5\textwidth]{example-image-a.pdf}}
\end{figure}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Note that the title should be short. Otherwise, the title goes on the top, unless we start playing with the width of the figure.

Comment: @emeryville For longer titles, you can use the `minipage=<length>` option; see my updated answer.